# Woocommerce checkout page not updating total price

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

i am using the newest version of Woocommerce (2.6.4) and i have an issue with my template globe-free.
As i am in checkout page and choosing different shipping method, it doesn't change the order total, as it does in the previous page (cart page).

I am searching around the net to find a solution but as i am not so familiar with wordpress i can't find the proper...please could somebody help me?
The url of the site is http://red-in.gr/
Thanks in advance...

Comment: do you have any caching plugins activated like w3 total cache?

Comment: It seems to be working